# Problems with the import statement

Tags: java, import

I've created the following java file:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Text {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "I AM A SENTENCE";
        String[] lines = wrap(str, 5);
        for (int i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            if (lines[i] != null) System.out.println(lines[i]);
        }
        Font myFont = new Font("Impact", Font.BOLD, 36);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(charToPixel(str, myFont)));
    }
    public static String[] wrap(String str, int w) {
        char[] string = str.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("string.length: " + String.valueOf(string.length));
        int charCounter = 0;
        String[] line = new String[20];
        String work = "";
        int x = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<string.length;i++) {
            charCounter++;
            System.out.println("charCounter: " + String.valueOf(charCounter));
            System.out.println("i: " + string[i]);
            if (charCounter > w) {
                charCounter = 0;
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(x));
                line[x] = work;
                x++;
                work = "";
                i--;
            }
            else {
                work += string[i];
            }
        }
        line[x] = work;
        return line;
    }
}
```

Now, I also created a simple applet that I want to use to receive the String[] and then one by one output it using Graphics.drawString().
I created a .jar file using the default manifest and the previous class file. The class file's directory is as follows within the jar: Dennis\Text.class.
I added my jar into the CLASSPATH.
I used the import statement as follows: `import Dennis.*;`

However when I compile the applet (btw the Text.class had compiled perfectly)
I get the following compilation error:

> bad class file: B:\Apps\Java\JDK\lib\Text.jar(Dennis/Text.class)
>       class file contains wrong class: Text
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

As far as I can tell, I put everything in the right place and the import statement was successful.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> The class file's directory is as follows within the jar: Dennis\Text.class.

It shouldn't be. It's not in any package, so it should just be directly within the root directory of the jar file. Ideally *put* it within a package (not `Dennis`, which violates Java naming conventions) and then make your jar file structure match the package structure.

Comment: @Guitarroka: If you've put it into a package, you'd have something like `import foo.bar.Text;` where `foo.bar` is the package name.

Comment: I remade the jar file and now it has only two files inside it (no directories) they are: MANIFEST-MF and Text.class

Comment: Also, how do I "package" something? Is there a special command or do I just put it into a folder within a folder in the jar?

Comment: You just need to use `package pkg1` statement at the top of your class.. It should be the first statement in your .java file..

Comment: @Guitarroka: These are very basic Java questions. I would *strongly* urge you to get hold of a good book on Java, or read a tutorial. Stack Overflow is great for answering specific questions when you're already up and running with a language, but it's not a good starting point to learn from scratch.